# How to get Http Body Message From a TCP packet in C#

Tags: c#, http, tcp, listener, pcap.net

i'm working on a tcp listener project on c#. I'm using pcap.net for packet capture. But when i'm trying to get the http message with such command like `tcp.Http.Decode(Encoding.UTF8)`, i get some encrypted script. I'm listening on sites that not using SSL protection. I tried `tcp.Http.ToMemoryString()` then decode it with UTF8 with bytes I can get the Http header properly but i cant get the HTTP message in a readable form. Any ideas how can i do it or am i missing something?

Comment: It could be compressed, check the transport encoding header

Comment: oh i' ve tried that too with gzip and deflate but there is a problem comes up with that too. A magic number error do you have any idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `HttpDatagram.Body` property to get the body.

This would return the parsed body part of the HTTP packet.

Note though that you are parsing a single packet, so you will only get the data from that packet, which might not contain the entire HTTP response body.

Comment: i get all packets of the site, it must be a data maybe a little bit of data must be in a packet. It's looking like compressed or encoded can you help me with that?

Comment: If it's not the first packet, you will have to first do TCP reconstruction and then parse the data.